# Launching android emulator using specflow

Tags: android, testing, xamarin, automated-tests, specflow

I'm trying to use specflow to create automated testing for a Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017. I've created a project which uses Nunit and specflow and created a feature file. I've seen it's possible to start a iPhone and do some automated testing, but I'm having problems on how to do this with android. I've read this [BDD Test with xamarin](http://arteksoftware.com/bdd-tests-with-xamarin-uitest-and-specflow/) where, as I understand, I should add this:

```
 public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform, string simulator)
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp
                .Android                   
                .StartApp();
        }

        return ConfigureApp
            .iOS
            .StartApp();
    }
```

However I cannot figure out how this will help me launch the simulator, and what I should pass as the string to start an android simulator.

Comment: Did you had a look at the final code from the blog post? It is here: https://github.com/RobGibbens/BddWithXamarinUITest

Comment: @AndreasWillich I did not, so what you suggest is that I start up the android emulator from commands prompt, via the ProcessStartInfo?